# SQL - Can I make use of a partition when checking the partitioned field against value from another table?

Tags: sql, performance, amazon-athena, partition

I'm querying in Athena SQL for the following use case:

I have a table A which is partitioned on Date:
Date | Number of Purchases | Category

In another table B, I have 500 events which happened on particular dates. I want to access aggregated data from A for the week before each of these events:
EventID | Event_Date | 7_Days_Before_Event_Date | Category

I would like to end up with, for each event, the sum of purchases for the 7 days before the date the event occurred.

However, when using a where clause for this eg. `A.Date between B.7_Days_Before_Event_Date and B.Event_Date`
the partition on A is no longer used, and all data is queried, vastly reducing performance.

How might I get the data for the week before each event while using the partition and therefore keeping performance high?

SQL Query:

```
select b.event_id, sum(a.number_of_purchases)
from dbo.tableA a
inner join dbo.tableB b on a.category = b.category
where a.date between b.7_days_before_event_date and b.event_date
group by b.event_id
```

Comment: Can you update your question with the SQL query?

Comment: Hi @PrabhakarReddy, absolutely, just updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Athena is based on presto and in presto your query is trying to dynamically generate values for `between b.7_days_before_event_date and b.event_date` clause and the value is not known until planning time, so your query ends up scanning all the partitions.

The community is already working on a feature called [dynamic filtering](https://github.com/prestodb/presto/issues/7428) which will helps in solving this kind of performance related issues.

You can also refer to [link](https://github.com/prestodb/presto/issues/9118) which talks more about this issue in detail and for possible work arounds.